# Why do Google Sheets filter ranges sometimes auto-expand to include new data, and sometimes don't?

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation, google-sheets-filter

When I create a filter in Google sheets, I want the range to automatically expand as I add/populate new rows. Sometimes, this works fine:

[image: Gif of range auto-expanding]

When I have a column using “Checkbox” data validation (required for my project), the range never auto-expands:

[image: Gif of range not auto-expanding]

My goal is to auto-expand the range whenever a new row is populated (also acceptable: auto-expand the range when a new row is first added) even when checkbox data validation is present.

I suspect I can accomplish this through a simple script, but I want to better understand the expected behavior. What is the logic for when the filter range auto-expands and when it doesn’t? I’ve searched the web but haven’t found a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

This bothered me too.  The trick is to *not* use "Add N more rows at the bottom" but rather, ensure that your ranges include an *empty row* at the end and always insert rows *above* it.  Rows added *inside* a range *are* added to the range, rows added outside aren't.  Obvious when you think about it and not really a problem unless you want to add lots of rows.